# Google Oauth wrong name

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth

I want to publish my app but Google is telling me that the app name is against theirs Data Policy.

> Based on the information you sent us, it looks like your project my-app-name doesn't show its identity to Google users when asking to access Google user data.
>
> Specifically, there's a problem with your project's app name. This violates Google API Services: User Data Policy.

My name in Oauth contain word "YouTube"/ the project is related to YouTube.
So this is the problem? I can't use the word in my app name? So can I use something like u2b? What kind of names are allowed?

I can't find it in the TOS/data privacy.

Thanks!

Comment: [Google API Services: User Data Policy](https://developers.google.com/terms/api-services-user-data-policy). I think you'll trigger the error with anything that could be considered to masquerade as a Google registered mark.

Comment: @DazWilkin Ok, so if I use short term, like: YT or You2be or similar? Is it fine?

Comment: I would encourage you to consider an entirely distinct name not only to avoid potentially raising Google's ire but to ensure that your customers aren't confused either.

Comment: @DazWilkin Ok, I got verified with YT in name. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my-app-name is not a valid name for your application.

You application name should clearly identifie your brand name as the company who created the application.

I would almost expect it to for example contain your domain name.

My could mean anyone again it needs to clearly identify your company or brand.

so no you can't name your app my-app-name and have it verified.

You also can't use any registered trademark names in your name unless you own the trademark

Stay away from anything remotely resembling a google product or potential google product

Comment: It's just an example. And the name (not Oauth screen name) doesn't matter, right?

Comment: Its the name in the consent screen that is the issue.   Please edit your question and include the name you have used not an example we can't help without all the information

Comment: Ok, the problem was in the OAuth name. The name can't contain word `Youtube`, but it can contain short form `YT`. Thanks for help anyway.

Comment: @Jaros yes that kind of what i mentioned in the last line of my answer.  Remember to accept the answer if it helped you it will also improve your own reputation.